# Problems to create a C# ClassLibrary in MacOS (.Net Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm quite confusing trying to create a .net core app in MacOs.

I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio) found here and everthing worked well, but when I tried to create another ClassLibrary with some other dependencies,  anything works and I can't understand why.

I installed the VisualStudio 2017 with .net core SDK , so I think that my Mac now has all [pre-requisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) to create my C# Libraries. For information, when I type `dotnet --version` I get `2.0.0`.

So I create a new ClassLibrary, and set the target framework to netStandard 1.4, foloowing the instructions [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), since I want that my library be used in another environments besides MacOs and NetCore.

The problem is that, apparently, net core 2.0 in my mac does not have all necessary assemblies to create the library, because a simple code like below is broken with the message

> "Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Cryptography' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?) (CS0234)"

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
```

Im have the code `using System.Security.Cryptography;` in the top of my file, so it should work since this module is [available since netstandard1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), right?

I know that I'm doing some type of confusion, but I want to understand where is my mistake.

Can I create a ClassLibrary in my MacOS targeting the netstandanrd1.4 even running the .NET CORE 2.0? If yes, where can I found the missing assemblies for .NET libraries? Should I install anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Standard 1.4 is only supported in .NET Core 1.0.  Not 2.0

[Reference of Supported Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

You can target a previous version of .NET Core by specifying this in your .csproj file by using the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Where can I found this info? Do you have any idea about what should I do to create my library using Mac that is compatible with other old implementations of netstandard?

Comment: I linked the reference article above.  You can target .NET Core 1.0 in your project.  I will update my answer on how to target .NET Core 1.

Comment: This is incorrect. .NET Standard are built ontop of one another. Anything that .NET Standard 1.4 supports, .NET Standard 2.0 should support. And you can add .NET Standard 1.4 libraries into a .NET Core 2.0 project.

Comment: @MindingData. Following the link in the question I also understood it (`The column header indicates the .NET Standard version that your target supports (and any lower .NET Standard versions will also support it).`, according to the link), but apparently it is not working or I'm doing something wrong. Targeting the netcore 1.0 looks like a usable solution for now. :/